# How can I modify internal state using .reduce() in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created function `get_marketing_updates_from_projects` from which returns modified list of array of objects.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchMarkets } from '../actions/MarketingCardAction';
import _ from 'lodash';

function get_marketing_updates_from_projects(projects)
{
  let all_marketing_plans = [];
  _.each(projects, function(project) {
    // all_marketing_plans = project.marketingplans.reduce(marketing_plan_array_reducer, all_marketing_plans);
      project.marketingplans.reduce( function(coll, marketing_plan){
          coll.push( _.extend(marketing_plan, {"project_name": project.name, "project_id": project.id}));
          return coll;
      }, all_marketing_plans );
  });

  console.log("All marketing plans", all_marketing_plans);
  return all_marketing_plans;
}

class MarketingCard extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        let marketing_plan_projects = [];

        this.props.markets.data ? marketing_plan_projects = this.props.markets.data : null;

        this.state = {
            marketing_updates : get_marketing_updates_from_projects(marketing_plan_projects),
            query: '',
        }
    }

    componentDidMount (){
        this.props.fetchMarkets();
    }

    filterMarketingUpdates = (marketing_updates) => {
        const formatQuery = this.state.query.toLowerCase();
        return _.filter(marketing_updates, marketing_update => {
            return this.contains(marketing_update.project_name, formatQuery);
        });
    };

    contains = (name, query) => {
        if (name.toLowerCase().includes(query)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    onQueryChange = query => {
        this.setState({ query });
    };

    render() {
        const filtered_marketing_updates = this.filterMarketingUpdates(this.state.marketing_updates);
        //console.log(filtered_marketing_updates)
        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Hello World</Text>

            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}  

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
       flex: 1,
       paddingLeft: 15,
       paddingRight: 15
    },

});

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    markets: state.markets.items
})

export default connect (mapStateToProps, { fetchMarkets })(MarketingCard);
```

Note: If I do `console.log(this.props.markets.data);` in render() then I am able to see entire data in console but now I want to perform reduce() operation on it but I am getting empty array []  why so ?

I just want to assign `this.props.markets.data` to `marketing_plan_projects` and then perform reduce() on `marketing_plan_projects` so that I can get `marketing_updates` i.e new modified data.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Could you copy your file exactly. Imports included. This way we can match up the line numbers properly

Comment: Is the error still exists? You changed your code several times from the first time you ask the questions.

Comment: @Bukhari I have modified the code and I am getting empty array in console ? Why so ?

Comment: @AndrewSteinheiser I have modified the code and I am getting empty array in console ? Why so ?

Comment: Can you also show your export & how you use the `connect` function (a.k.a. include your `mapStateToProps` / `mapDispatchToProps` - Also can you show what your `.reduce` function looks like?

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher I have added check it out. I just want to assign `this.props.markets.data` to `marketing_plan_projects` and then perform reduce() on `marketing_plan_projects` so that I can get `marketing_updates` i.e new modified data

Comment: Your assignment of marketing_plan_projects seems a little weird. Try it like this: let marketing_plan_projects = this.props.market.data ? this.props.market.data : null; Also, just for testing purposes, try assigning data directly to it, to see if your get_marketing_updates_from_projects() method is actually working as you want it to.

Comment: @rrd I did as you said but I am getting null in console if I do ` console.log(marketing_plan_projects)` so when the data ( i.e `this.props.markets.data`) is completely fetched (initially it is empty) then only it should assign it to `marketing_plan_projects`

Comment: @rrd If I do `console.log(this.props.markets.data)` inside constructor I am getting undefined so should I do the assignment operation outside constructor ?

Comment: @funjoker can you show what your sample data looks like so we can see if your `reduce` function is doing the right thing?

Comment: @funjoker I create demonstrate here https://jsfiddle.net/a3n6w4rf/1/ but i don't know how is your `this.props.markets.data` structured. check console for the result

Comment: @Bukhari The problem is why I am not able to access this.props.markets.data inside constructor ? I am getting undefined ? My data: http://jsfiddle.net/d9u3z2ny/

Comment: @Blundering Philosopher  The problem is why I am not able to access this.props.markets.data inside constructor ? I am getting undefined ? My data: http://jsfiddle.net/d9u3z2ny/

Comment: @funjoker what did you got when log `this.props.markets.data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Since you fill props on `DidMount` you might need to change state when you props changed. So you might need to declare `WillReceiceProps` event.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  // You don't have to do this check first, but it can help prevent an unneeded render
  let marketing_plan_projects = [];

  nextProps.markets.data ? marketing_plan_projects = nextProps.markets.data : null;
  const marketing_updates = get_marketing_updates_from_projects(marketing_plan_projects);

  if (!_.isEqual(marketing_updates, this.state.marketing_updates)) {
    this.setState({
      marketing_updates,
    });
  }
}
```